# How do I write a conditional Ruby case statement with parameters passed into the case?

Tags: ruby, regex, case-statement

I'm trying to figure out a way for a `case` statement to take into account two parameters passed in from a regex.

My regex example is:

When `(/^(?:a|an|the) (RoleA|RoleB)` attempts to access a `(New|Updated) Record$/)` do `|role_type, record_type|`.

I have a `case` statement that only accounts for role type right now, but how do I also have the case portion account for `role_type` and `record_type`?

My goal is to test that Role A is directed to a different set of endpoints when the record type is "New" or "Updated" and I want Role B to be directed to another set of endpoints when passing in "New" and "Updated". If they were being passed into the same endpoints, then a case statement for `record_type` only would suffice.

What I have right now is:

```
case record_type
   when 'New'
     <do something>
   when 'Updated'
     <do something>
 end
```

I'd like to  switch the behavior based on what the role is. This  didn't work:

```
case record_type && role_type == 'RoleA'
   when 'New'
     <do something>
   when 'Updated'
     <do something>
 end

case record_type && role_type == 'RoleB'
   when 'New'
     <do something>
   when 'Updated'
     <do something>
 end
```

This code is skipped over and I'm assuming that Ruby is confused about which statement to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass an "argument" to `case`. The first term after `case` is an expression that returns the object it will match upon, and the expression you put in returns either `true` or `false`. You can either put it all inside an `if` expression, or put the two objects in an array and match on the whole array:

```
case [record_type, role_type]
when ['New', 'RoleA']
  ...
when ['New', 'RoleB']
  ...
when ['Updated', 'RoleA']
  ...
when ['Updated', 'RoleB']
  ...
end
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! And now I'm clearer on how the && operator resolves.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is not "confused" you just only have 2 cases:

```
case record_type && role_type == 'RoleA' # true or false
```

because `record_type && role_type == 'RoleA'` will only evaluate to true or false I think more what you are looking for is:

```
case role_type
  when 'RoleA'
    case record_type
       when 'New'
         #do something
       when 'Updated'
         #do something
    end
 when 'RoleB'
    case record_type
       when 'New'
         #do something
       when 'Updated'
         #do something
   end
end
```

That being said I would recommend looking into whether refactoring this is possible into something simpler like

```
def new_record(role_type)
  if role_type == 'RoleA'
    #do something
  elsif role_type == 'RoleB'
    #do something
  end 
end

def updated_record(role_type)
  if role_type == 'RoleA'
    #do something
  elsif role_type == 'RoleB'
    #do something
  end
end 

acceptable_record_types = ['New','Updated']
public_send("#{record_type.downcase}_record",role_type) if acceptable_record_types.include?(record_type)
```

This could be refactored even more if I understood the similarities between `#do something`

Comment: This also worked! I guess I was the one confused. And I will definitely see what I can do about creating a method for this. Thanks!